# Intermittent SQL Server Connection Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, database-connection

I have been experiencing an intermittent SQL connection problem that I can't resolve.  First of all I will explain the setup:

Windows 2008 R2 Standard SP1 (and all patches delivered through windows update):

- This server runs IIS 7.5
- The ASP.NET MVC 4 Web App runs within it's own App Pool
- The App Pool identity is used to set permission on the folder containing the code
- The Web App passed a username and password in the connection string - server xxx; database=xxx; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=xxx; Password=xxx; Pooling=False; Network=DBMSSOCN;
- elmah used to log errors

Windows 2008 R2 Standard SP1 (and all patches delivered through windows update):

- This server runs SQL Server 2008 R2 Web Edition SP2
- TCP/IP is the only enabled Client Protocol

These are VM's hosted by our cloud provider.  The cloud provider has investigated, from an infrastructure point of view, but cannot find any problems.

The error messages generated are as follows:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 9 - Associating port with I/O completion mechanism failed)
```

I've been unable to find any information on error code 9.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

While these errors are generated, IIS will show the 'friendly error' page.  It usually takes around 15 minutes for the issueto resolve itself or an IISReset.  When this issue first occurred I downloaded a SQL Load  Generator from codeplex and ran test up to 300 simultaneous connections with multiple query's and everything was ok.  I also ran another test while the web app was generating the SQL exceptions - all connections from the load test succeeded.  This really confused me!?!

No Event Logs are created during the outage.

To me the error message indicates a problem connecting to the SQL box, however the load test run during the most recent outage contradicts this - yet IIS is still serving content (configured error message).

I realize that this is a difficult question, however I would be very grateful for any advice regarding techniques to find the cause of the error.  Any information on what error 9 relates to would also be helpful.

Comment: I see that no one else has posted a reply or fix. I wanted to add an interesting find. I experience this issue on LOCALHJST, but when I publish the project to my dev server, the problem is not encountered. Perhaps there are some restrictions on the source of the connection coming into the SQL server.

Comment: Running locally, it works for me to stop the IIS server and let VS create a new one for you. Never had it happen multiple times in the same day / project / session.

Comment: Having the same problem on AWS (cloud) getting SqlException `Win32Exception (0x80004005): An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket` seems totally random and can't find a solution :(

Comment: @markpirvine did you ever get to the bottom of this? we have a similar issue - in particular it seems to resolve itself within 15 minutes

Comment: @DavidMasters no I never did get to the bottom of this - there was a redesign and we no longer use SQL Server (unrelated to the issue). Are you running in Azure? There have been a number of issues lately following DNS updates Microsoft have made.

Comment: Not Azure, but AWS....here's my issue. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56255267/intermittent-sql-connectivity-issue-with-aws-rds

Comment: @DavidMasters that is interesting, this issue was also with AWS - could be an issue with how RDS is provisioned. Have you got business support? We have and the quality of the response has always been very high - costs about £100 per month.